# Como usar conjuntos de "if-else" corretamente no C?

Tags: c, if, else

Estou com um problema neste código no DevC++, pois ao meu ver a parte das condições de `if-else` está perfeitamente indentada e organizada (todo `if` possui seu `else` e suas chaves). O erro está no último `else`, mas não sei como resolver, pois preciso dessa condição.

O objetivo do programa é classificar os 3 valores inseridos um triangulo, e se formarem, classificar em equilátero, isósceles e escaleno. No entanto, se não formarem um triangulo, emitir mensagem. É nessa parte que está o problema, pois o programa não compila se eu inserir essa última condição.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, 
system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int a, b, c;
char equi[] = "Triangulo equilatero.";
char isos[] = "Triangulo isosceles." ; 
char esc [] = "Triangulo escaleno."  ;

scanf("%d", &a);
scanf("%d", &b);
scanf("%d", &c);

if ((a > 0) && (b > 0) && (c > 0) && (a<(b+c)) && (b<(a+c)) && (c<(a+b)))
{
    if( (a==b) && (b==c) )
    {
        printf("%s", equi);
    }else{
        if( (a==b) || (b==c) || (c==a) )
        {
            printf("%s", isos);
        }else{
            printf("%s", esc);
        }   
    }

/* O problema está aqui neste ultimo else abaixo, pois se eu retirar essa 
linha o programa compila. No entanto se eu deixar, dá um erro "id returned 1 
exit status".*/

}else{
    print("Nao e possivel formar um triangulo."); 
} 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uma dica que eu te daria é utilizar else if (){} para uma melhor performance do código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não está perfeita indentado e não está bem organizado, não é tão fácil ler e este é um dificultador. Há um erro de digitação onde tem um `print()` quando na verdade deveria ser `printf()`. Veja como fica mais fácil de seguir o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);
    scanf("%d", &c);
    if (a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && a < b + c && b < a + c && c < a + b) {
        if (a == b && b == c) printf("Triangulo equilatero.");
        else printf((a == b || b == c || c == a) ? "Triangulo isosceles." : "Triangulo escaleno.");
    } else printf("Nao e possivel formar um triangulo."); 
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WMrqsP). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/npfakliw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/Printf.c).